# Angular Breadcrumb Navigation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router, angular-breadcrumb

I've been trying to build a breadcrumb navigation system for angular.

The problem I'm having is my breadcrumb.service seems to be listing the Home page twice....

[image: home-page]

[image: page-2]

Code is on Stackblitz here - [Stackblitz Editor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c4hggi?file=src/app/services/breadcrumb.service.ts)

It's something about going through the addBreadcrumb() loop the first time.

(Also, I give credit to https://github.com/ocanzillon/angular-breadcrumb as I started off looking over his project)

My breadcrumb.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Data, NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Breadcrumb } from '@core/models/breadcrumb';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class BreadcrumbService {

  // Subject emitting the breadcrumb hierarchy
  private readonly _breadcrumbs$ = new BehaviorSubject<Breadcrumb[]>([]);

  // Observable exposing the breadcrumb hierarchy
  readonly breadcrumbs$ = this._breadcrumbs$.asObservable();



  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.pipe(
      // Filter the NavigationEnd events as the breadcrumb is updated only when the route reaches its end
      filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe(event => {

      // Get the url "/page-1/page-2"
      const root = this.router.routerState.snapshot.root;

      // Create empty breadcrumb array
      const breadcrumbs: Breadcrumb[] = [];

      // Make first call to addBreadcrumb function
      this.addBreadcrumb(root.firstChild!, [], breadcrumbs);

      // Emit the new hierarchy
      this._breadcrumbs$.next(breadcrumbs);

    });
  }

    buildDepth(iterations: number, constituentFolders: string[]) {
      // This module builds links from the various preceeding folders
      // /page-1
      // /page-1/page-2
      // /page-1/page-2/page-3

      var depthStr="";
    
      for (let i=1; i<=iterations; i++)
      {
      // Add each of the folders to the string
          depthStr=depthStr + '/' + constituentFolders[i];
      }

      return depthStr;
    }


  private addBreadcrumb(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, parentUrl: string[], breadcrumbs: Breadcrumb[]) {
    if (route) {


      // Get the route url
      const routeUrl = parentUrl.concat(route.url.map(url => url.path));

      // Break the route into seperate folders /page-1/page-2/ becomes and array of [page-1], [page-2]
      let constituentFolders: string[] = new Array();
      constituentFolders = routeUrl.toString().split(",")

      // I need to add 'home' route at the start to match with the empty '' url.
      constituentFolders.splice(0, 0, 'home');

      // Iterate over the folders, building breadcrumb links for each part of the url.
      // Don't do the last folder as that's the current page.
      for(let i = 0; i < (constituentFolders.length); i++){

        // Add a breadcrumb link
          const breadcrumb = {
            label: this.getLabel(constituentFolders[i]),
            url: this.buildDepth(i, constituentFolders)
          };
          breadcrumbs.push(breadcrumb);

        // Recursive call to next element in the route.
        // pass in the route's first child.
        this.addBreadcrumb(route.firstChild!, routeUrl, breadcrumbs);

      }
    }
    
  }

  getLabel(input: string){
    // get the label name from the folder taken from the route
    // page-1 becomes "page 1"
    return input.replace(/-/g, ' ');
  }


}
```

The breadcrumb.component.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Breadcrumb } from '@core/models/breadcrumb';
import { BreadcrumbService } from '@core/services/breadcrumb.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-breadcrumb',
  templateUrl: './breadcrumb.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./breadcrumb.component.scss']
})
export class BreadcrumbComponent {

  breadcrumbs$: Observable<Breadcrumb[]>;

  constructor(breadcrumbService: BreadcrumbService) {
    this.breadcrumbs$ = breadcrumbService.breadcrumbs$;
  }

}
```

The breadcrumb.component.html

```
    <ol id="breadcrumbNav" class="breadcrumb-nav">
    <li *ngFor="let breadcrumb of (breadcrumbs$ | async)">
      <a [href]="breadcrumb.url">{{ breadcrumb.label }}</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
```

And finally the CSS just adds the " > " chevrons after the links, but not the last link.

```
    .breadcrumb-nav {
    & {
      list-style: none;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  
    li {
        display: inline-block;          /* display list in a row */
        padding-left: 5%;
  
      /* Display chevron before each link */
      &:before {
        content: " > ";
        margin: 0 6px;
      }
  
      /* Don't display chevron after the first link */
      &:first-child:before {
        content: "";
        margin: 0;
      }
    }
  }
  

.breadcrumb-nav a {
    color: #45768b;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.breadcrumb-nav a:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

Thanks

UPDATE:

I think it's because the default url is localhost:4200/home so there's an additional 'Home' in the first array...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
showing the problem.
You could use 
[stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)
 to make one.

Comment: I added the stackblitz editor link at the top :)

Comment: There's a library that provide declarative and dynamic breadcrumbs https://www.npmjs.com/package/xng-breadcrumb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I see now! It is the default label + the default path name. The first `home` label in the welcome screen is the label set by default in this line:

```
constituentFolders.splice(0, 0, 'home');
```

in your service file.

And the second `home` is coming from the `redirectTo: 'home'` set in the `app-routing.module.ts` when the path is empty. You have to remove either of them to have an ideal view of the `breadcrumb`, whereby you will have one `home` label by default and when you pick page one you will `NOT` get a duplication of `home` label.

The first approach (the easiest):

1- Go to `app-routing.module.ts`
2- Instead of this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home', // <-- This from where the second label is coming
    pathMatch: 'full',
  }
]
```

To ensure that the default URL will be hosting the HomeComponent and you will not duplicate the label you can just do this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomePageComponent
  }
]
```

3- Results:

[image]

Thus, I think you do not need to set the `home` route in your `app-routing.module.ts` but make the default empty URL points to this component.

The second approach is to either add a conditional check in the service or rework the method to not have a hardcoded default value called `home` in your breadcrumb component. That's to say that the route tree will be constructed from index 0 dynamically starting from whatever the initial landing screen component route name is. Let me know if the first one is not suitable and you need to rework the service part.

I think the first one resolves your issue.

Here is [your updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z16po7?file=src/app/app-routing.module.ts)

Comment: I went with your second idea. Just removing the home route still leaves " home > " at the top. Instead in breadcrumb.service.ts :
      if (constituentFolders[0] != 'home') {
        constituentFolders.splice(0, 0, 'home');
      }

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is - in breadcrumb.service.ts

```
  // I need to add 'home' route at the start to match with the empty '' url.
  // The route maybe localhost:4200/home so a 'home' will be in constituentFolders[0]
  // We don't want to add a second 'home' then.
  if (constituentFolders[0] != 'home') {
    constituentFolders.splice(0, 0, 'home');
  }
```

[image]